# Is there any way to call the form load on button click in vb.net when using this kind of logic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2019

```vb
Public Class form1
    Dim var1 as String = ""
    Dim var2 as Boolean = True

    Public Sub New(ByVal parameter1 as String, ByVal parameter2 As Boolean)
        var1 = parameter1
        var2 = parameter2

        InitializeComponent()
    End Sub

    Private Sub form1_Load(sender as Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        If var1 = "This String" Then

        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub btn_Save_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_Save.Click
        call form1_load()
    end sub
```

I was unable to call the form load with parameters, can somebody please help on this, thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

`form1_Load` is just a method that you can call like any other method. The Form_Load method requires a sender and an EventArgs parameter. You can just pass through the ones you get from Button_Click.

```vb
Private Sub btn_Save_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_Save.Click
    form1_load(sender, e)
End Sub
```

But a better solution is to extract the logic into a new method and to call it in both, Form_Load and Button_Click.

```
Private Sub DoSomething()
    If var1 = "This String" Then

    End If
End Sub

Private Sub form1_load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles form1.Load
    DoSomething()
End Sub

Private Sub btn_Save_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_Save.Click
    DoSomething()
End Sub
```

Note that calling `form1_load` does not raise the `Load` event. It only executes the logic inside this method.

Comment: H, i tried with the specified logic , but the error remains same as Public Sub New(ByVal parameter1 as String, ByVal parameter2 As Boolean) carries parameters, but Im trying again :) Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: If `New` has parameters, you must specify those parameters when creating the form. E.g. `Dim frm = New form1("param1", "param2")` (but this has nothing to do with your question).